# Commute to work on Google Maps tracking is innacurate

Tags: google-maps

My wife tracks me through Google Maps. I have no problem with that. However it keeps showing I stopped at certain locations when I never did. it shows several different routes I took to my job, I don't understand how to read this. I've done everything on all the forums to improve my accuracy. Also, both of our emails are on each others phones. Could the app be tracking two different phones at once? I was wondering if that could be an issue.

Comment: What kind of phone do you have?

Comment: Kyocera Hydro Xtrm

Comment: Try using the [Life360 app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.life360.android.safetymapd), which is a free service designed to let you track family members' locations.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a possibility to the app is tracking two different phones at once is quite impossible. Even though you tried on all the forums already, I suggest you to do a simple way.

1. If you are using Android, go to "settings" -> find  "apps" -> click on "maps" and then stop it.
2. Restart your phone and open "maps" app again.

This has already happened with friends and instruction above was the solution for it.